# PHP delete item from Shopping cart

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array

I created a very simple shopping cart that just add item s to it and delete items from it and empty the cart too now I know I have a lot of issues in my code but I am trying to fix them as well

first see my code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $c) {
        echo $c['name'] . '<br />';
        echo $c['price'] . '<br />';
        echo '<a href="?pid=17&rc=' . $c['code'] . '">Remove item</a><br />';
    }
}


if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    //header("Location:?pid=18&pl=" . $pl);
    if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
        $getData = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id=?');
        $getData->bind_param('i', $pl);
        if ($getData->execute()) {
            $res = $getData->get_result();
            if (($pn = $res->fetch_object()) !== null) {
                $proCode = rand(1, 100);

                $item['name'] = $pn->plan_name;
                $item['price'] = $pn->price_dollar;
                $item['code'] = $proCode;
                $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<a href="?pid=17&ac=empty">Empty Cart</a>';

if (isset($_GET['rc']) && isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $rem = $_GET['rc'];
    $ses = $_SESSION['cart'];

    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $cartItem) {
        if ($cartItem["code"] == $rem) {
            unset($ses[$rem]);
        }
    }

    /*if (($key = array_search($rem, $ses)) !== false) {
        unset($ses[$key]);
    }*/
    var_dump($ses);
}

if (isset($_GET['ac']) == 'empty' && isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

for now the adding new products is working fine with me but the issue
comes when I am trying to remove one item from the caret it return back and noting seems to happened, and the item still there in the cart

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without seeing how your cart works as a whole. It could be a few different issues, but without seeing how this script is being called, it is hard to determine what might be going wrong. My suspicion is that in your delete, you are removing the item from $ses, but not $_SESSION, so when your cart reloads, the item is still in the session. Can't be for sure though without seeing the whole module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your deleting cycle to this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$cartItem) {
        if ($cartItem["code"] == $rem) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are unsetting `$ses` variable not `$_SESSION`...

Please have a look at the updated code, you dont even need to use a `forloop`, you can just `unset` the variable as I done below

```
 if (isset($_GET['rc']) && isset($_SESSION['cart'])) 
 {
    $rem = $_GET['rc'];    
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$rem]))
    {
       unset($_SESSION['cart'][$rem]);
    }
}
```

let me know if this help you

**EDIT**

Please update your buy product function to below one.. you are using `auto increament key for array`.. it should be the **primary key (here your product code)**

```
if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
    //header("Location:?pid=18&pl=" . $pl);
    if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
        $getData = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id=?');
        $getData->bind_param('i', $pl);
        if ($getData->execute()) {
            $res = $getData->get_result();
            if (($pn = $res->fetch_object()) !== null) {
                $proCode = rand(1, 100);

                $item['name'] = $pn->plan_name;
                $item['price'] = $pn->price_dollar;
                $item['code'] = $proCode;
                $_SESSION['cart'][$proCode] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry same results noting is deleting and the item is still there by the way `ses` was equaling the `$_SESSION['cart']`